# Nutch : Anchor text of current URL

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

In an indexing filter, is there a way to figure out the Anchor text from which the current URL/document originated from? I tried the inlinks but that seems to be null.

```
public NutchDocument filter(NutchDocument doc, Parse parse, Text url, CrawlDatum datum,          Inlinks inlinks) IndexingException {

    //Need to know the anchor text from which the current document originated from at this  point

}
```

If the current URL is say http://foo.com/pagex the the link to pagex must've been found at http://foo.com. I need to know the anchor text of this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor text is found in the inlinks, but for this to be populated, both `db.ignore.internal.links` and `linkdb.ignore.external.links` have to be set to `false` in `nutch-default.xml`. Alternatively, they can be overriden in `nutch-site.xml`.